# How to route all network traffic through a Kubernetes pod?

Tags: kubernetes, vpn

I have a pod which run OpenVPN client, to connect a VPN. And I have other pods that runs several applications. Theese applications needs to use this VPN to reach some resources.

How can I route the pods network traffic through the VPN pod?

Comment: have you had a look here? https://docs.k8s-at-home.com/guides/pod-gateway/#how-to-debug